# How to set a cast value in a bracket?

Tags: sql, casting

I am trying cast two datas. I want the cast data within a bracket. I have tried like this:

```
SELECT EmpCode,
       (CAST(Name AS varchar(50))+' '+CAST(EmpCode AS varchar(50))) AS Name
from ShiftAllocation
```

It gives output with Name and EmpCode like

> Tom Varghees 12345

But I want this 12345 (EmpCode) in a bracket. 
Expected output is

> Tom Varghees [12345]

What changes I should do in my sample querym

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [QUOTENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx).

```
SELECT EmpCode, 
       (CAST(Name AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' ' + 
       QUOTENAME(CAST(EmpCode AS VARCHAR(50)))) AS Name 
FROM   ShiftAllocation
```

---

If you don't have ability to use `QUOTENAME` you can go in following:

```
SELECT EmpCode, 
       (CAST(Name AS VARCHAR(50)) + 
       ' [' + CAST(EmpCode AS VARCHAR(50)) + ']') AS Name 
FROM   ShiftAllocation
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add parenthesis, no rocket science needed:

```
SELECT 'Peter'+' ['+ '12345'+']' AS Name
```

in your query:

```
SELECT EmpCode,(CAST(Name AS varchar(50))+' ['+CAST(EmpCode AS varchar(50)) +']') AS Name from ShiftAllocation
```